# Portfolio Weight Constraints

Tags: finance, excel

[image]

Hi,

So I was asked to calculate the maximum sharpe ratio using solver in excel but it gave me really big numbers for the portfolio weights. So I was wondering what is a good constraint to add and why is it bad or if it is even feasible to have portfolio weights so heavily in a long or short position?

Cheers.

Comment: if your issue is large portfolio weights then consider ridge regression or lasso regression. They are both regularisation techniques which you can investigate on wikipedia

Comment: You can also add constraints for the following:
1. Beta of the portfolio
2. Volatility of the portfolio (Standard Deviation)
3. Leverage of the portfolio, as defined as `sum(abs(weight))`

Comment: Don’t use excel if you want to be taken seriously.  R and python both have really good libraries (eg cvtopt or scipy) to optimize including constraints.